# A game may related to graph theory or topology

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

Last Sunday, I played a game with a group of people. The game is as follows:

A group of people form a circle as shown below:
[image]

Each person must remember how he/she is linked with his two neighbours. For example, A remembers that his left hand grabs B's right hand and his right hand grabs C's left hand.

Then a judge separate these people and make their position random. After this, every person stand still and grab the hand of his original neighbours, in the way as before. (In the example above, A must still take B's right hand by his left hand, and C's left hand by his right hand.) Now the people are in a twist.

The purpose is to return to a circle as fast as possible without ever breaking up the hands. One can step over arms and hands can go over heads. The restored circle does not require that all the people must still face to the center of the circle.

**There is a debate to whether a solution always exists.**

I hope you can understand my (poor) description and give me a rather rigorous (but understandable) proof. I am so interested in this problem.

#### Edit

How they recover the original position, what are the legal moves? Any method is allowed given that their hands are not separated. By "their hands should not separated" I mean their hands are touched all the time, you can twist your hands if needed, but at **every** moment you can't lost your neighbors' hands.

Comment: I suspect the existence of an untangling movement, without unclasping hands, may depend on whether specific people have  grabbed hands above or below some other persons' hands.  See the [trefoil knot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trefoil_knot) for an illustration of this potential complication.

Comment: How are hands hold before and after the rearrangement? It also matters. If hands are supposed to clasp in the same way as before maybe the trefoil is not possible. Say A started graving B's hand with B's hand inside A's hand and both thumbs pointing up. Should this description be preserved?

Comment: @hardmath Don't mind how hands hold, we only require hands do not seperate

Comment: @Nathanson see above comment

Comment: the authorized moves aren't clearly defined. If only one has been permuted with a hole, he may move from its position to a new hole made by the translation of the other players to get its original relative place and the previous hole disappears. When a move is forbidden ? In which case can he cross over linked hands ? Is there a supplemental information like the order the hands linked again after the separation or the way the links are interlaced ?

Comment: @igael I have added some information.

Comment: there are a lot of difficulties in general but one can work on conditions to a solution, particularly at the time where they join again from their random assigned places. I have the image, it needs a math formalism and all the context has to be stated. Perhaps tomorrow

Comment: 18 months then I can take one or 2 days more ! If I don't find how to provide an answer in the Mse format, I'll publish my notes and add a bounty to the question. But , right now, hope to answer is not null

Comment: @igael Why you so busy, what did you do?

Comment: I'm trying to prove an heuristic ; this needs a lot of formalism and notation but for the moment , the solution not using a lot of topology , it's not really math, just a sequence of tricks ... and perhaps a discutable good answer ( lacks of exhaustivity ). Tomorrow, I'll try to use matrices